# Problem using role_has_cap hook

Tags: hooks, capabilities

I'm trying to filter a capability check in order to work around the lack of filters to customize the user edit page in the admin area. But I can't seem to add filters to a hook, and I'm sure I'm missing something basic here.

The hook in question is `role_has_cap`, located at line 343 of `wp-includes/capabilities.php`. It reads:

```
$capabilities = apply_filters( 'role_has_cap', $this->capabilities, $cap, $this->name );
```

I'm trying to test my filter by adding this to my `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('role_has_cap', 'my_role_has_cap_filter', 10, 3);
function my_role_has_cap_filter($var_one, $var_two, $var_three) {
    print_r($var_one);
    print_r($var_two);
    print_r($var_three);
}
```

But absolutely nothing happens. Even if I add the filter with less parameters than my function requires (which, in my limited knowledge, should trigger a PHP error) I'm completely ignored by WordPress.

What I'm actually trying to achieve is returning false to a `current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )` or `current_user_can( 'edit_pages' )` when viewing `user-edit.php` on the admin area, **without actually removing those capabilities**, but the fact that a filter is not applying seems to me more relevant that my ultimate goal.

Comment: Do you have `WP_DEBUG` set to `TRUE`? Further: Try to wrap your filter call inside a function that you hook during `init`.

Comment: I do have WP_DEBUG set to TRUE. I've wrapped it around a function on init, but still get nothing.

Comment: Oh. You always need to `return` the 1st argument in the list.

Comment: Plus: The filter should only work if you're actually questioning if some role has a cap in one of your templates (for example). Else the fn won't get triggered.

Comment: I'm on user-edit.php, so there are certainly current_user_can() being called all around (the two I've specified in the question are certainly being triggered). I've added a return statement, but nothing has changed.

Comment: The filter is inside a function that returns true or false, it won't produce output, not in the way it's used. If you want to dump that data, just do it inside the core file directly(wp-includes/capabilities.php), then undo the changes when you're done seeing what you need to see.

Comment: If you're on `user-edit.php`, does that mean that you're on that admin UI page or are youhacking core?

Comment: I'm visiting that page on the browser, but that's a really good question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

To start with, I was using the wrong hook. I should have been using `user_has_cap` hook instead, which is what actually has a chance of being called when using `current_user_can()`.

But second, and most important of all, I was seeing the page while logged-in as super_admin, which didn't trigger the `apply_filter` function at all. Since by definition the super_admin has **all** capabilities, WP doesn't feel the need to filter any of the checks.